# How to popViewController and send back data

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code to go back to the last view controller

```
  self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

How do I send data back to the last view controller as I do this?

Comment: Are you using dismiss or pop to go back?

Comment: Pop I’m using not dismiss

Comment: You can use delegate method or post a notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift relies a lot on the delegate pattern and this is a good place to use it.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    func pushToSecondViewController() {
        let second = SecondViewController()
        second.firstViewControllerDelegate = self // set value of delegate
        navigationController?.pushViewController(second, animated: true)
    }
    
    func someDelegateMethod() {
        print("great success")
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var firstViewControllerDelegate: FirstViewController? // establish a delegate
    
    func goBackToFirstViewController() {
        firstViewControllerDelegate?.someDelegateMethod() // call delegate before popping
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One common way is to use delegate pattern. Pass the viewController back with some data using the delegate method and dismiss it from “parent” ViewController.

See these links for extra daya about delegates
[link1](https://www.appcoda.com/swift-delegate/)
[link2](https://learnappmaking.com/delegation-swift-how-to/)